# How to put correct date on invoice PDF in Magento 2?

Tags: date, invoice-pdf, magento2.3.4

Invoice PDFs are generating the incorrect date, I have this on two sites both on 2.3.4 and en_GB locale

e.g.

> $order->getCreatedAt()

```
2020-02-14 11:14:40
```

becomes

> $this->_localeDate->formatDate(
>                   $this->_localeDate->scopeDate(
>                       $order->getStore(),
>                       $order->getCreatedAt(),
>                       true
>                   ),
>                   \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM,
>                   false
>               )

```
13 August 2019
```

This is coming form:

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/AbstractPdf.php

Removing the scopeDate() function fixes it, but should I do this or is it a configuration error on my part somewhere?

Comment: Are you able to solve this ? in invoice PDF showing wrong date

Comment: This is Magento issue, you can check my answer in https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/312969/magento-2-invoice-pdf-date-is-showing-wrong/327638#327638

Answer (score 1):

The same issue for me and solve with this code fix
Navigation to this file `/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/DateTime/Timezone.php`

and Replaced this function to :

```
public function scopeDate($scope = null, $date = null, $includeTime = false)
    {
        $timezone = new \DateTimeZone(
            $this->_scopeConfig->getValue($this->getDefaultTimezonePath(), $this->_scopeType, $scope)
        );
        switch (true) {
            case (empty($date)):
                $date = new \DateTime('now', $timezone);
                break;
            case ($date instanceof \DateTime):
            case ($date instanceof \DateTimeImmutable):
                $date = $date->setTimezone($timezone);
                break;
            default:
                $date = new \DateTime(is_numeric($date) ? '@' . $date : $date);
                $date->setTimezone($timezone);
                break;
        }

        if (!$includeTime) {
            $date->setTime(0, 0, 0);
        }

        return $date;
    }
```

Run the command and check your result