# Magento 2 Invoice PDF date is showing wrong

Tags: orders, sales-order, invoice, magento2.3.4, invoice-pdf

Magento 2 order date showing wrong in Invoice PDF,the order date is showing correct in admin order page but it is not showing correct when generate invoice PDF.

Magento 2 admin order page(looks good) please check screenshot
[image]

When generate invoice PDF then in PDF date is showing wrong please check screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is Magento issue, you can apply patch

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26675 - Magento issue 26675

https://pastebin.com/YtzX09gL - patch

1. `composer require cweagans/composer-patches`
2. Create root subdirectory called patches and create file `datetime_format_2_3_5.patch.
3. Add pastebin content to this file (https://pastebin.com/YtzX09gL)
4. Add to your composer.json:

[image]

5. And run `composer update --lock`

*(with composer-exit-on-patch-failure set to true, composer will complain if the patch is no longer applicable on a certain version of Magento, which is very handy.)*